# Windows 10 Pro won't sleep after installing VMWare Player

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, sleep

HP EtherDesk 800 Windows 10 Pro. After installing VMWare Workstation Player 15, the machine will no longer go into 'sleep' mode.

I've seen other answers saying that installing -any- Virtual Box software disables sleep, but I am pretty sure that I have run VMWare Player (earlier versions) on Win 10 without this problem.

I checked in Services.MSC and there are several Hyper-V related services, but none are started.

I've also checked all the 'normal' settings for Power and Sleep, including the Virtual Network drivers for Wake On Lan that VMWare Player installs. Nothing has worked.

Is there a way to re-enable Sleep? (Or at -least- the screen saver?)

Comment: "I've seen other answers saying" - Which answers?

Comment: To be clear: this happens even if VMware Player isn't open and no VMs are running?

Comment: Yes. It happens even with VMWare Player not running.

Comment: I have Workstation 16 Player installed, and my PC won't sleep when a VM is running but will sleep if the program is closed. In the past it would successfully sleep regardless of whether a VM was running or not. Not sure what changed.